# C# Entity Framework - Multiple Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a problem with Entity Framework 6 code first creating multiple foreign keys from my classes when it should only create one. Consider I have 2 classes -

```
public class Work
{
    public Work()
    {
        Document1 = new Collection<Document>();
        Document2 = new Collection<Document>();
        Document3 = new Collection<Document>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Document1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Document2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Document3 { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public int? WorkId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("WorkId")]
    public Work Work { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I run the code first ***update-database*** command, in my documents table it creates 3 different foreign keys for the Work table **WorkId**, **Work_Id1**, **Work_Id2**, this should just be one foreign key instead of 3. I know there should be a simple annotation to fix this or a fluent mapping I need to add?

Comment: `Work` is connected to `Document` by three properties (collection) Document1, Document2 and Document3. Thats why it is creating three foreign key. If you wanted to specify only 1 foreign key how other two will be connected to Document entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently a `Work` may have zero or more `Document1`, zero or more `Document2` and zero or more `Document3`. All these documents are of type Document.

Each Document belongs to exactly one `Work`, in which it is either a `Document1`, a `Document2` or a `Document3`. The problem is when using your classes it does not know which Document type it is.

The most database friendly and flexible solution is to give each document a property, telling which type of Document it is, and put all Documents into one table:

```
public enum DocumentType
{
    Document1,
    Document2,
    Document3,
};

public class Work
{
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Document { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public int DocumentId {get; set;} // primary key
    public DocumentType DocumentType {get; set;}

    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    public Work Work { get; set; }
}
public MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Work> Works {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Document> Documents {get; set;}
}
```

The result is one Table with Documents. column WorkId will tell you to which Work the document belongs. Column DocumentType will tell you whether it is a Document1, a Document2 or a Document3.

This way it will be easy to add new DocumentTypes without having to change the database. If you want fast searches for all documents of a certain type consider creating an extra index with keys (Id, DocumentType)

If you really want three different tables, for instance because it could be that in future a Document1 is not similar to a Document2 anymore, you'll have to create three classes derived from Document, and three DbSet for these classes

```
public class Document1 : Document
{
   public int WorkId {get; set;}
   public virtual Work Work {get; set;}
}
public MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Work> Works {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Document1> Document1s {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Document2> Document2s {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Document3> Document3s {get; set;}
}
```

Consider using [Table-per-concrete-class](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) for this. This way you'll get a table with Document1, a table with Document2 and one for Document3

Answer (score 1):

Your `Work` class has three collections of `Document`, so the `Document` class requires three keys to denote where it attaches. If I have an instance of `Document` whose `WorkId` is 4, where does that exist on the instance of `Work` with that ID? Does it belong in `Document1`, `Document2`, or `Document3`? With only one key, there is no way to determine this. Entity Framework knows this, and has created three keys to solve the problem.